# Is there a format for numeral.js that will show decimals only when needed?

Tags: javascript, string-formatting, numeral.js

tests: http://jsfiddle.net/su918rLv/

This is the how the existing formats work:

```
numeral(1234.567).format('0,0');
//output: 1,235

numeral(1234.567).format('0,0.00');
//output: 1,234.57    

numeral(1234).format('0,0.00');
//output: 1,234.00
```

Is there a format that will produce both a whole number or decimal number based on the number value? I'm using `0,0.99` here but it is not the answer.

```
numeral(1234).format('0,0.99');
//output: 1,234

numeral(1234.567).format('0,0.99');
//output: 1,234.57
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Yes. Put the optional decimals in brackets:

```
numeral(1234).format('0,0.[00]');
// output: 1,234

numeral(1234.567).format('0,0.[00]');
// output: 1,234.57
```

Comment: Thanks! It also works in [numbro.js](http://numbrojs.com/format.html): `numbro(1234).format('0,0.[00]')` and `numbro(1234.456).format('0,0.[00]')`

Comment: I have a related question but couldn't find an answer. What if I want to show all decimal places in tact based on the value? For example I want to show 1,234 and 1,234.56 and 1,234.567 respectively as it is

Comment: @bruce: put as many optional places as you need. Eg. `0,0.[000000]` will format numbers with up to 6 decimal places if number has that many or more.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Thanks it makes sense, my mind was stuck when I asked that question XD

Comment: Is there a way to optionally force two decimals for currency? I wouldn't want to display $100.1, for example.

Comment: To optionally force two decimals for currency, `'$0,0[.]00'` works for me.

Comment: Is there a place where I can see all the possible things I can do in the format string?

Answer (score 7):

Either no decimals or 2 decimals:

```
numeral(1234).format('0,0[.]00');
// output: 1,234

numeral(1234.5).format('0,0[.]00');
// output: 1,234.50
```

(Based on johnwp's comment from the accepted answer).